# how to get selected index on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how I will get selected Item index on mouseover ..I have a list , when I mouseover the list I added hover class .But I need the selected Item .

here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/qp6ex1jh/

```
 $(function(){
 $('#main-menu').on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                console.log("mouse over")    
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                  console.log("mouse leave")    
                }
            });

 })
```

when I hover on **B** it give me `1` and when I hover `c` it give me `2`

Comment: Why not attach an event handler to the list items then instead of the div container?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Within event handlers `this` is element that event occurred on. You probably want event on children

Comment: I want if I hover to second item it give me 1 ..or I hover third item it give me 2

Comment: using hover I want to get the index of item ..

Comment: I think you are searching for `$(this)` pointer. The index of `<a>` will be zero always, because is the only children in `<li>`. To get the index you need to read the `<li>` item index, not the `<a>`, but however, it's better if you need to point to that element to use `$(this)`

Comment: yes I need to read li index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and move selector to the `<li>`

```
$('#main-menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("over index " + $(this).index())
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      console.log("leave index " + $(this).index())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this JS ;)

$(function(){
      $('#main-menu li').on({
               mouseenter: function () {
                    alert($(this).index())    ;
          },
     });
 })

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the list items. In this way, `$(this)` will contain the piece of information you need and with jQuery [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function you can obtain its index:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#main-menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("mouse over: " + $(this).index())
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      console.log("mouse leave: " + $(this).index())
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#main-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu">
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to get index not text

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property [`counter`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/css-generated-content-counters/) no JS, please review the demo.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/uqgfkz5s/)

**Snippet**

```css
li {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 'Consolas';
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1ex;
  margin: 0 0 0 2ex;
}

li:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover:before {
  content: idx;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 0 1ex;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 2ex 0 0;
}

li:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: idx -1;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: idx;
  content: counter(idx);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-menu">
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>A</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>B</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>C</a>
      </li>
            <li>
        <a>D</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>E</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>F</a>
      </li>
            <li>
        <a>G</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>H</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>I</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</div>
```