# how to add the index on mouse over event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two list .I am getting index of list item on mouseover .As example `A` has 0 index .`B` has 1 index..But I want to add index in other words if user mouseover the second list `A` .it gives output `9` not 0..

I am getting `0` on second list first time ..I want it add length of first list if user mouse over the second list.

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/e46atunm/1/

```
$(function() {
  $('#main-menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("mouse over: " + $(this).index())
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      console.log("mouse leave: " + $(this).index())
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Please put all relevant html in the question itself. Questions should be self contained so the whole issue is clear without having to go off site

Comment: See my answer for a pure [CSS solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35780038/2813224).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple case of `index()` using `$(selector).index()` just indexes siblings.

You can also index within collections you define using `$(collectionSelector).index(element)`:

```
var $li =  $('#main-menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("mouse over: " + $li.index(this))
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      console.log("mouse leave: " + $li.index(this))
    }
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e46atunm/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: What are expected results then. Works fine for me when i append the value https://jsfiddle.net/e46atunm/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work

```
$(function() {
  $('#main-menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      var before = $(this).parents('section').prevAll().find('li').length;
      console.log("mouse over: ", before+$(this).index());
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      var before = $(this).parents('section').prevAll().find('li').length;
      console.log("mouse leave: ", before+$(this).index());
    }
  });
})
```